# Leaflet Image Overlay Add Marker By pixel coordinates

Tags: leaflet

How to add an marker to leaflet map image overlay by using the image pixel coordinates.

I need to place an marker into map by the image's actual pixel xy coordinates by mentioning the x,y pixel points

Check this Fiddle link for more info.

```js
var osmUrl = 'path/to/custom/image',
  h = 709,
  w = 709;

var map = L.map('mapid', {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 1,
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 1,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

L.imageOverlay(osmUrl, bounds).addTo(map);
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
// var markerData = [[0,0],[185,362],[277,593],[307,354],[472,472],[473,568],[550,516],[535,370],[230,119]];


var marker = L.marker(map.layerPointToLatLng(map.containerPointToLayerPoint([185, 362])));
marker.addTo(map);
```

```html
<div id="mapid" style="width:500px;height:400px;></div>
```

Comment: Check this demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/1rLggm0z for more

Comment: Have you read http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html ?

Comment: Can we place a marker with actual pixel x,y points on map using leaflet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Your map center was wrong. The axis origin is at the top-left corner.

```
var map = L.map('mapid', {
    minZoom: -3,
    maxZoom: 1,
    center: [0, -709],
    zoom: 1,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
```

Check [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rLggm0z/14/) and [that other one](http://jsfiddle.net/1rLggm0z/15/).

Comment: It is not working as expected in responsive design.
Can you check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4whzLbve/).